# How do I display columns from two common table expression?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, union

I have problems displaying columns from two common table expression. I created the first table by querying the student names and their mid-term grades and the other table the student names and their final-term grades.

```
  CREATE TABLE MidTerm AS (SELECT Name, Score
                           FROM GRADE
                           WHERE TYPE = ''MidTerm
  )
  CREATE TABLE FinalTerm AS (SELECT Name, Score
                           FROM GRADE
                           WHERE TYPE = 'Final'
  )
```

Both of the created have the same number of columns and the same variables. Now I want to display the Name, Score "MidTerm" and Score "FinalTerm", how can I achieve this? I manage to use UNION at the expense of SELECT * only. If I specify

```
 Midterm table:

              Name : Score
               A   : 50
               B   : 60
 Finalterm table:

              Name : Score
               A   :  70
               B   :  80
```

I want to join the CTE tables by displaying

```
     Final Intended Result:
                          Name : Score "MidTerm" : Score "FinalTerm"
                           A   : 50              : 70
                           B   : 60              : 80
```

it would say invalid column identifier. How do I solve this?

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL. Please show what parts of your goal you can do.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Edited the explanation above

Comment: Still no [mre]--Give the exact error message & code we can cut & paste to cause it & edit your words. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. (Debugging fundamental.) Ask about that.

Comment: You seem to simply want an inner join on name. MRE please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple join will handle this:

```
SELECT m.NAME AS "Name",
       m.SCORE AS "Score MidTerm",
       f.SCORE AS "Score FinalTerm"
  FROM MIDTERM m
  LEFT OUTER JOIN FINALTERM f
    ON f.NAME = m.NAME
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4fae6df107cb61439f4ab33a1dbf77e1)

Answer (score 1):

If you have two tables for midterm and final score as per comment in gordon's answer then just do `join` and you will get your result like this:

```
Select m.name, 
       M.score as midterm_score,
       F.score as final_score
From midterm_table m
Join final_table f 
  on (m.name = f.name);
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are just looking for conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    name, 
    max(case when score = 'MidTerm' then score end) MidTerm,
    max(case when score = 'Final' then score end) Final
from grade
where score in ('MidTerm', 'Final')
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

I am baffled.  Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'MidTerm' THEN Score END) as midterm_score,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Final' THEN Score END) as final_score,
FROM GRADE
GROUP BY Name;
```

CTEs do not help with this query at all.

You could *also* do this using a `JOIN`:

```
select m.name, m.score as midterm_score, f.score as final_score
from grade m join
     grade f
     on m.name = f.name and
        m.type = 'midterm' and
        f.type = 'final';
```

Note that this only shows `name`s with both scores.

Comment: I'm supposed to save the result of the first query (more complex, but I show the above for simplicity) to a table (MidTerm) and then save the second query to the other table (FinalTerm) with the change in the condition in Where Clause... After that, I'm supposed to display the name, midterm score, finalterm score from the two created table...

Answer (score 0):

Add student's id in those tables and use it to join them and gather the columns that you need.

I dont believe that create this two tables is realy a good idea, 
but, ok, I don't know the complexity of your calculations to get the score.

anyway, I would suggest to you consider the creation of an view for that instead of create those table.